# How to make better Line Chart in UWP?

Tags: uwp

I am using winrtxamltoolkit.controls.datavisualization.charting for showing line chart in my UWP application but It does not seem to be same as required.

**This is the requirement**

[image: This is the requirement]

**This is how it looks in my app.**

[image]

Comment: Provide us the code you have tried, so we can help you with specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

have you thought about trying out other alternatives such as [Syncfusion](https://www.syncfusion.com/uwp-ui-controls/charts), [Live charts](https://lvcharts.net/), or [FlexChart](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GrapeCityinc.FlexChartforUWP)?

Alternatively you could write your very own. I would say you could start with the Canvas control and draw shapes on it based on the input data. This way you have full control over the look and feel, but it is way more complicated than using a third-party library.
By the way you need a solution that handles out-of-bound values and show them differently from normal values.